# calculate change frequency for CMS page

Tags: php, content-management-system

I am thinking of the best way to automatically calculate the change frequency of a CMS content page for a XML sitemap.

Do I:
Create another table that on save/create from the CMS content page it inserts into the table "content_versions" each time. To calculate the change frequency I can then count the amount of times it has been updated in the last year.

Is there another way I can do this? I though I could maybe store each edit in a serialized column in the contents table.

Although for the change frequency I would calculate it like this to be dynamic

```
if($period > 60*60*24*365) { // > 1 year
    $freq='yearly';
} elseif($period > 60*60*24*30) { // > 1 month
    $freq='monthly';
} elseif($period > 60*60*24*7) { // > 1 week
    $freq='weekly';
} elseif($period > 60*60*24) { // > 1 day
    $freq='daily';
} elseif($period > 60*60) { // > 1 hour
    $freq='hourly';
} else { // < 1 hour
    $freq='always';
}
```

- Planning on allowing the user to over right the change frequency if they want to.
- Restrict only 1 change log per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to allow the content editor decide that - he should be the best qualified to know the exact update frequence. Considering that the user would make 'updates' to correct spelling or grammar errors, changing a picture or other very small and insignificant changes, could give a wrong impression of the actual update frequency when trying to calculate it.

On the other hand, if you don't trust your users input, calculating it, could be the only way.

An idea would to have two fields in your table; last_published and last_updated; calculating the difference between the two could give a small idea of how often the user updates the content - probably just as precise as the 7 timestamps for correcting errors.

Conclusion? I would let the user tell my CMS how often he expects to update the content.

Comment: Its more the fact that 95% of users editing the CMS are very busy running their own business without having another option to fill out or me have the time to teach each them what it means. I was planning on adding the functionality to allow them to override the change frequency but auto calculate if not.